# Удаление тегов html вместе с их содержимым

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, ajax

Как удалить элемент html страницы?

Answer (score 2):

Пример удаления элемента по id.

```html
<div id="idForDelete">123</div>


<script>
document.getElementById("idForDelete").remove();
</script>
```

Если необходим более сложный пример, то, пожалуйста, опишите подробнее ваш вопрос.